# Polynom arc algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, pseudocode

In class we saw the followin problem but i didnt undestand the solution. Do anybody could explain me with more detail the procedure to solve this problem or give me a better solution?:

> Assume that n points in the plane are given. Find a polygonal arc with n-1 sides whose vertices are given points, and whose sides do not intersect.(Adjacent sides may form a 180 angle). The number of operations shold be of order n log n.

The teacher solution was:

> Sort all the points with respect to the x-coordinate; when x-coordinates are equal, take the y-coordinate into account, then connect all the vertices by line segments(in that order).

Answer (score 2):

The solution of your teacher is (fortunately) good. I'll try to visualize this for you.

Just draw the points on a plot. Then you can draw a line from the leftmost point to the next point. This way, connect all points going to the right.

If all the points have different x-coordinates, that'll work out, and no lines will cross:

[image: drawing from the left to the right]

For the points with the same x-coordinates, we first go to the lowest (smallest y-coordinate) and then go up. No crossing there, either.